# Getting Exceptions from logs on *nix using sed/awk/whatever

Tags: java, regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to get exceptions from log files created by tomcat.
 
Yes, I did some research, but because I don't have any experience with sed or awk - adjusting what I've found to what I need is kinda difficult.
A sample file is shown below to have something to work on:

```
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '503: Service Temporarily Unavailable' when communicating with http://66.66.66.66:1234/aaa/bbb/ccc
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1546)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    ... 39 more
2014-10-24 11:40:01,558 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.SomeClass] - some exception on parsing '2007/11/45' bla bla
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '503: Service Temporarily Unavailable' when communicating with http://66.66.66.66:1234/aaa/bbb/ccc
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1546)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 32 more
2014-10-24 11:40:01,561 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd] - some error with id = 1214
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
2014-10-24 11:44:48,253 INFO [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] - Closing Hibernate SessionFactory
2014-10-24 11:44:48,253 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - closing
2014-10-24 11:44:48 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
2014-10-24 11:44:50 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8096
```

As we can see there are: 2 FULL EXCEPTIONS (we want them), 1 PARTIAL EXCEPTION(we dont want it). To make this example short I deleted some important stuff, like log4j:ERRORs, which we dont want.
so far I tried:
AWK (its my 1st day with AWK, please dont laugh :D). its pretty straight forward.
it finds "/t" (tab) + at + " " (empty space) in the beginning of every line. if 2 lines before it match given conditions (Exception and date) it prints them too. it works pretty well, but it also prints partial exception, which we DO NOT want.

```
BEGIN {
    preprevious = "";
    previous = "";
}
/^\tat / {
    if( previous != "" ) {
        if(preprevious ~ /20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/){
            print preprevious;
            preprevious = "";
        }
        if(previous ~ /.*Exception/) {
            print previous;
            previous = "";
        }
    }
    print;
    next;
}
 { preprevious = previous;
    previous = $0; }
```

which i run like this:

```
awk -f awkScript testFileExceptions.txt
```

and SED in a bash script (I prefer that)

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -eq  "2" ]
    then
        tail -n $2 $1 | sed -n "/ ERROR \[/,/20[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/p"
    else
        echo "usage: scriptName filePath amountOfLastLinesInFile"
fi
```

it matches '" "+ERROR+" "' (with empty spaces on both sides of ERROR, so log4j:ERROR will not be matched) to date. it kind of works...
disadvantages: 
1)it will work IF there are some additional lines between exceptions - like this:

```
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
        ... 32 more
2014-10-24 11:40:01,561 INFO [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd] - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2014-10-24 11:40:01,561 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd] - some error with id = 1214
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

if not - then the 2nd exception will not be shown
2)it will also print out the last matched line (which is the one with the date match)

so to sum up, what I want on outcome is:

```
2014-10-24 11:40:01,558 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.SomeClass] - some exception on parsing '2007/11/45' bla bla javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525) 
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '503: Service Temporarily Unavailable' when communicating with http://66.66.66.66:1234/aaa/bbb/ccc
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1546)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
        ... 32 more

2014-10-24 11:40:01,561 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd] - some error with id = 1214 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

I also want to save different exceptions to different files (lets say exceptionOutputNNN.txt, for example exceptionOutput001.txt), but I'll figure it out later, shouldn't be that hard after I figured out how to do that for XMLs... :P

well.. that's it. I hope someone can help me:)
cheers

edit: please note, that Exceptions can end with "... NN more" and with simple "\tat org.*"

Comment: a kind request: if you guys can't help me - please vote for this question, so maybe others will see it

Comment: Can you reduce the example input and output please.

Comment: Done. Is it short enough or should it be even shorter?

Comment: Yes i'll have a look in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure exactly what you want
This should work for what output you want though

```
 awk '/^[0-9]+/{x=0}/ERROR/{x=1}x' file
```

#### output

```
2014-10-24 11:40:01,558 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.SomeClass] - some exception on parsing '2007/11/45' bla bla
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '503: Service Temporarily     Unavailable' when communicating with http://66.66.66.66:1234/aaa/bbb/ccc
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1546)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 32 more
2014-10-24 11:40:01,561 ERROR [aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd] - some error with id = 1214
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:525)
```

Edit: For your original file

```
 awk 'a=/^[0-9]+/{x=0}a&&/ERROR/{x=1}x' file
```

or

```
 awk '(/^[0-9]/&&x=/ERROR/)||x' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I still have to figure out WHY it works, but it works ;]

Comment: could you please help me in understanding this?<br>
    /^[0-9]/&&x=/ERROR/<br>
seems to match lines beginning with either a number (date) or containing ERROR. cool. but what is this "x" doing there? and why if we use "||x|" awk prints all the lines after matched line?

Comment: @WrRaThY do you have any programming experience? It will be difficult to explain exactly how it works if you don't.

Comment: Yes, i do :) I just have no idea how AWK works (for example I thought that i need to call "print" to print a line. and looks like I dont have to...)

Comment: if there is no action block after an argument eg `x' instead of `x{command}' then it defaults to print. `x` is set to the value of `/ERROR/` which evaluates to `1` if it is found. `/ERROR/` is only evaluated if `/^[0-9]/` is found as it short circuits at the `&&` if not.

Comment: so the x is set to 0 (which means the line wont be printed) if awk finds a line starting with a date, but without ERROR in it? cool XD

Comment: @WrRaThY yep pretty much :)

Answer (score 0):

for any people viewing this post in the future, below is the script which uses Jidders solution and saves output to files (1 file perexception)

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$#" -eq  "2" ]
    then
        rm output/errorOutputFile* 2>/dev/null
        tail -n $2 $1 | awk '(/^[0-9]/&&x=/ERROR/)||x' | awk '/^[0-9]/{g++} { print $0 > "errorOutputFile"g".txt"}' 
    else
        echo "usage: scriptName filePath amountOfLastLinesInFile"
fi
```

cheers